# Selenium webDriver 2.46 hanging on switching windows using switchto.window

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have a scenario in our Test Case, where we have to switch control from Parent window to child window(Separate).

We are able to do it on Chrome and FF using following code:

```
Set<String> winHandles = gblConstants.objdriver.getWindowHandles();

System.out.println(gblConstants.objdriver.getWindowHandles().size());

for (String winHandle : winHandles )
{

if(!(winHandle.equals(Keywords.parentWindowHandle)))
{

  WebDriver driver = gblConstants.objdriver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

  blnRes = true;

  driver.window().maximize();

  break;                            

}             
}
```

But when we try to execute the above code on **IE11**, the execution freezes at:

```
 WebDriver driver = gblConstants.objdriver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
```

*Client* : Java,

*Selenium WebDriver* - 2.46

*OS* : Windows 7

Please help in getting this work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any exception Or error message you get??  Also share if you have used Desired capabilities

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem until someone reminded me to run the configuration script we use to set up IE for webdriver testing.  Likely one (or more) of these guys will do the trick for you.  My tests are no longer hanging at least.

```
@ECHO OFF
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom" /v "ZoomFactor" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x000186a0 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1" /v "2500" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" /v "2500" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" /v "2500" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\4" /v "2500" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Check_Associations" /t REG_SZ /d "no" /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation" /v "IntranetCompatibilityMode" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Recovery" /v "AutoRecover" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000002 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" /v "Flags" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000043 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\global.pvt\*.pbi" /v "*" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000002 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2" /v "2101" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000000 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client" /v "RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000002 /f
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that new version of selenium is not supporting properly to IE11. Please try with below code.It looks similar to ur code. But, it might work.

String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
            Set handles2 =  driver.getWindowHandles();
               for(String windowHandle  : handles2)
                   {
                   if(!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow))
                      {
                      driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
                      driver.window().maximize();
                     break;
                      }
                   }